# Product of Permutations- Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find the product of the permutations: (1,2,3)(2,4,3,5)(1,3,2) 
From what I've been taught in my Abstract Algebra class, the product of permutations is in fact a composition of permutations. So, in cyclic notation, I got my answer to be (1,5,3,4) (2). However, Wolfram Alpha tells me that my answer is incorrect. I must be missing something here. The way I solve these is the following: I treat each permutation as a function. So let's say our 3 functions are f,g,h. f composed with g composed with h = f(g(h)). So let's say I want to know where 3 goes to, I take f(g(h(3))= f(g(2))= f(4)= 4. And I do this for all of the other elements. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: I think it's likely the notation confused Wolfram or perhaps it did things in the incorrect order. Your solution is correct.

Comment: You don't have to write $(2)$, with that said, your solution is correct.

Comment: What a relief. I've been second-guessing myself here for over an hour. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any error in your work. I'm getting the same answer. Can you provide the link to the Wolfram|Alpha computation that says your answer is false? Thanks.

Comment: @learner : Sure thing. I added a screenshot to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says on the W|A page, "the product $\sigma \tau$ represents the permutation $\tau(\sigma(\cdot))$." So they're just using the opposite, "left-to-right" notation. For instance, they get the cycle $(3)$ because $3$ is mapped to $1$, then $1$ is mapped to $1$, then $1$ is mapped to $3$.

Comment: Oh haha, that explains it. Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score -1):

this opposite way of expressing the composition is quite prevalent. Even JA Gallian does this way in his book on abstract algebra.

Comment: This is a fairly perfunctory post for a two year old Question.  Does it add anything to the existing (and Accepted) Answer?  If so you should highlight the new information.  Most Readers (myself included) will not know what book you are referring to by giving only the author and general subject matter.  A more complete citation (title, date, perhaps publisher) and a page reference with quote on the order of composition for permutations would be more helpful.